# source_data R from private repository

Tags: r, git, github, data-science, httr

I am trying to read one RData file from my **private** repository "data" in R

```
library(repmis)

source_data("https://github.com/**********.Rdata?raw=true")
```

This is my output

```
Error in download_data_intern(url = url, sha1 = sha1, temp_file = temp_file) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

Other way

```
script <-
  GET(
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/***/data/contents/01-wrangle-data-covid-ssa-mx-county.R",
    authenticate(Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT"), ""),     # Instead of PAT, could use password
    accept("application/vnd.github.v3.raw")
  ) %>%
  content(as = "text")

# Evaluate and parse to global environment
eval(parse(text = script))
```

Anyone knows how can I read this data from my private repo in R?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this.

1. Generate on GitHub your personal token 
   1.1 Go to GitHub 
   2.1 In the right corner go to "Settings" 
   2.2 Then in the left part go to "Developer setting"
   2.3 Select the option "Personal access tokens"
   2.4 Select the option "Generate new token"
   2.5 Copy your personal token
2. **On your home directory** follow the next steps 
   2.1 Create the file .Renviron

```
macbook@user:~$ touch .Reviron
```

On this file write your personal token like this:

```
macbook@user:~$ nano .Reviron
GITHUB_PAT=YOUR PERSONAL TOKEN
```

3. Now on R, you can check if your personal token has been saved with this:

```
Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")
```

also you can edit your token on R with this:

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

Don´t forget to restart R to save your changes.

**3.** Finally on R these are the line codes that will load your data from private repos

```
library(httr)

req <- content(GET(
  "https://api.github.com/repos/you_group/your_repository/contents/your_path_to your_doc/df_test.Rdata",
  add_headers(Authorization = "token YOUR_TOKEN")
), as = "parsed")

tmp <- tempfile()
r1 <- GET(req$download_url, write_disk(tmp))
load(tmp)
```

Comment: minor typo 

`macbook@user:~$ nano .Reviron` missing n

Comment: At least in R-studio you seem to need to restart (R or the project?) before it detects the new object in `.Renviron` ... otherwise `Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")` leads to a blank response